# Replace a single value with multiple values

Tags: python, numpy

Given a `mask` numpy array such as:

```
mask = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...])
```

I want to replace each `1` with a `target` **vector**. Example:

```
target = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
mask =   np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,...])
output = np.array([0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, ...])

# Overlaps:
mask =   np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,...])
output = np.array([0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, ...])
```

Naivly, one can write this via the following (ignoring boundary problems):

```
output = np.zeros_like(mask)
for i, x in enumerate(mask):
  if x == 1:
    output[i:i+len(target)] = target
```

I'm wondering, whether this is possible without resorting to a for loop?

Comment: Since the `mask` blocks can vary  in length, this iteration is probably the simplest.

Comment: Hm , what if it was constant length? Any tricks?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` supports assigning value for the same index multiple times in one go, like so:

```
mask =   np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
padding_idx = [2,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,8,9,8,9,10,11]
padding_values = [5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2]
mask[padding_idx] = padding_values
>>> mask
array([0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2])
```

You just need to find out `padding_idx` and `padding_values`.

Note that `padding_values = [5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2]` has one value missing. So you need also to find a number of values missing. After that you can use [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
vector = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
N = len(vector)
mask =   np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
missing_values = len(mask) - idx[-1] - N

#Broadcast
padding_idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)[:,None] + np.arange(N)
padding_values = np.repeat(vector[np.newaxis, :], len(idx), axis=0)

#Flatten
padding_idx = padding_idx.ravel()[:missing_values]
padding_values = padding_values.ravel()[:missing_values]

#Go!
mask[padding_idx] = padding_values
>>> mask
array([0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but some thoughts: The for loop is O(n), where `n = len(mask)`. We can use `np.split` to get that down to O(k), where `k = number of 1s in mask`:

```
def set_target(mask, target):
  output = []
  i, = np.where(mask == 1)
  for split in np.split(mask, i):
    if len(split) > len(target):
      split[:len(target)] = target
      output.append(split)
    else:
      output.append(target[:len(split)])
  return np.concatenate(output, 0)
```